# Can I use git without the GCM on Windows?

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

Is the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.blog/2022-04-07-git-credential-manager-authentication-for-everyone/) required on a Windows system? In the past I have been installing git-scm and unchecked `Git Credential Manager` sofar without and adverse effects.

Installing additional ways of checking credentials just adds an attack vector to the system I believe and Windows comes with its own credential manager.

Am I missing out on some functionality? Not opinionated just wondering.

Comment: The git credential manager is there especially to store the credentials in the native credential store so windows credential manager...

Comment: You *can* use Git without *any* credential managers, as long as you use ssh URLs. You can use HTTPS URLs with other credential managers. Whether you're "missing out on some functionality" is another question, one I'm not prepared to answer. 

Comment: Ok. so on Windows the GCM is a front-end to Windows Credentials Manager and not a store in itself?